# Sequelize optimistic locking not working?

Tags: sequelize.js

I already set version:true in my modal. But the version only increases, in the case that I pass old version to data updated, it still increase my version without throwing error OptimisticLockError [SequelizeOptimisticLockError] ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, hope this will help someone:

```
const newData={...,version:11}
const data=await modal.findOne({...})
Object.assign(data,newData)
data.dataValues.version=11 // this line will help u fix this bug
await data.save()
```